# cant get Landscape to deploy OpenStack

Tags: juju, openstack, landscape

no matter what I try, it hangs between 50 and 82%. I've tried everything from the minimum servers, to 6 servers and 3 public networks, I've tried Kilo, Liberty, maas 1.8.3 and maas 1.8.2 and I'm stumped.

the vast majority of core lxc are showing "message: Waiting for agent initialization to finish"

Right now I'm stuck at 82%  I'm going to leave it here so hopefully someone can help me troubleshoot.

can anyone help? I've been fighting this for about 3 weeks now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try to use juju direcly with MAAS at first, and succeed in deploying the simple charm "ubuntu".

Here are instructions on how to configure juju to use MAAS: https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.8/juju-quick-start.html

Then, after bootstrapping, try:

```
juju deploy ubuntu
```

If that works, ssh into that unit to confirm, and that you can reach the internet by trying something like `wget http://ubuntu.com`:

```
juju ssh ubuntu/0
```